# parsing access.log to data.frame

Tags: regex, r, parsing

I want to parse an access.log in R. It has the following form and I want to get it into a data.frame:

```
TIME="2013-07-25T06:28:38+0200" MOBILE_AGENT="0" HTTP_REFERER="-" REQUEST_HOST="www.example.com" APP_ENV="envvar" APP_COUNTRY="US" APP_DEFAULT_LOCATION="New York" REMOTE_ADDR="11.222.33.444" SESSION_ID="rstg35tsdf56tdg3" REQUEST_URI="/get/me/something" HTTP_USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" REQUEST_METHOD="GET" REWRITTEN_REQUEST_URI="/index.php?url=/get/me/something" STATUS="200" RESPONSE_TIME="155,860ms" PEAK_MEMORY="18965" CPU="99,99"
```

The logs are 400MB per file and currently I have about 4GB logs so size matters.

Another thing.. There are two different log structures (different columns are included) so you can not assume to have the same columns always, but you can assume that only one kind of structure is parsed at a time.

What I have up to now is a regex for this structure:

```
(\\w+)[=][\"](.*?)[\"][ ]{0,1}
```

I can read the data in and somehow fit it into a dataframe using `readlines`, `gsub` and `read.table` but it is slow and messy.

Any ideas? Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for example:

```
text <- readLines(textConnection(text))
## since we can't use = as splitter (used in url) I create a new splitter
dd   <- read.table(text=gsub('="','|"',text),sep=' ')
## use data.table since it is faster to apply operation by columns and bind them again
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dd)
DT.split <- DT[,lapply(.SD,function(x) 
             unlist(strsplit(as.character(x) ,"|",fixed=TRUE)))]
DT.split[c(F,T)]
```

Comment: In HTTP_USER_AGENT you have space characters so this wouldn't work

Comment: @frinx No it works fine for me. spaces are between quotes so it will not be detected by `read.table`.

Comment: true.. tnx, let me try

Comment: @frinx cool. I ma curious to know if this is efficient on your real data.

Comment: The code you provided is very similar to what I have, but you gave me a good hint for using read.table. I can read everything only by using `x <- read.table(fileName, sep=" ", fill = TRUE)` and now I would need is something to go over the whole dataframe and take only the value form KEY=value.

Comment: P.S.  I still have to write the script going over all this so then I can tell you how efficient it is

Comment: everything takes quite long and then just the conversion to data table is very long so this is not an option